# simple drag and drop in angular ondrop, ondragover, ondragstart

Tags: angular

I am trying to make simple drag and drop methods in my component and I can't seem to get this working. This is really the first time I have ever dealt with drag and drop type stuff so not sure if I am taking the right approach. Just adopting a tutorial from W3. Any suggestions? The id would be to simply get the id of the element being dragged and the id of the element dropped and append...

template:

```
<div id="opened" class="board-body" (ondrop)="drop($event)" (ondragover)="allowDrop($event)">
    <div class="card bg-light-blue mb-2" id="drag1" draggable="true" (ondragstart)="drag($event)">
        draggable card 1
    </div>
</div>
<div id="responded" class="board-body" (ondrop)="drop($event)" (ondragover)="allowDrop($event)">
    <div class="card bg-light-blue mb-2" id="drag2" draggable="true" (ondragstart)="drag($event)">
        draggable card 2
    </div>
</div>
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-funnel-grid',
  templateUrl: './funnel-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./funnel-grid.component.scss']
})
export class FunnelGridComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    allowDrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    drag(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.id);
        console.log(e.target.id);
    }

    drop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 29):

You just need to change the event names:

- (ondrop) to (drop)
- (ondragover) to (dragover)
- (ondragstart) to(dragstart)

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the (drop), (dragover), and (dragstart) functions given by Ryan T, there is also (dragend) which is called when the drag is canceled. Like if you release the drag over an invalid part of the screen. This is useful, for example, you're highlighting the drop zone on dragover and want the highlight to disappear when the drag is cancelled.